# Не работает функция сохранения поста

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, vue.js, spring-boot

Метод сохранения поста в форме

```
import { sendPost } from 'util/ws'

save() {
    sendPost({id: this.id, text: this.text})
    this.text = ''
    this.id = ''
}
```

Функция, которая импортируется в форму

```
export function sendPost(post) {
    stompClient.send("/app/changePost", {}, JSON.stringify(post))
}
```

Вот код в контроллере

```
@MessageMapping("/changePost")
@SendTo("/topic/activity")
public Post change(Post post){
    return postRepo.save(post);
}
```

Выдает вот такую вот ошибку в консоли

[image: Выдает вот такую ошибку в консоли]

Comment: stompClient.send существует? Ругается именно на это

Comment: Да проблема, уже решена, просто сам сокет не подключался из-за условия с ошибкой, но сейчас все работает